# Java - How to test if a String contains both letters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex which will satisfy both conditions.

It should give me true only when a String contains both A-Z and 0-9.

Here's what I've tried:

> `if PNo[0].matches("^[A-Z0-9]+$")`

It does not work.

Comment: I don't see any need to build one regex to accomplish both matches.  It would be much quicker (and easier to read) to call `String.matches()` two times and `AND` the two results (see my answer).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I suspect that the regex below is slowed down by the look-around, but it should work regardless:

```
.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+$")
```

The regex asserts that there is an uppercase alphabetical character `(?=.*[A-Z])` somewhere in the string, and asserts that there is a digit `(?=.*[0-9])` somewhere in the string, and then it checks whether everything is either alphabetical character or digit.

Answer (score 23):

It easier to write and read if you use two separate regular expressions:

```
String s  =  "blah-FOO-test-1-2-3";

String numRegex   = ".*[0-9].*";
String alphaRegex = ".*[A-Z].*";

if (s.matches(numRegex) && s.matches(alphaRegex)) {
    System.out.println("Valid: " + input);
}
```

---

Better yet, write a method:

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    String n = ".*[0-9].*";
    String a = ".*[A-Z].*";
    return s.matches(n) && s.matches(a);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A letter may be either before or after the digit, so this expression should work:

```
(([A-Z].*[0-9])|([0-9].*[A-Z]))
```

Here is a code example that uses this expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([A-Z].*[0-9])|([0-9].*[A-Z]))");
Matcher m = p.matcher("AXD123");
boolean b = m.find();
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: I think you should make it clear that this only works if you compile the `Pattern` and use with `Matcher`. It won't work with `.matches()` in `String` class.

Comment: Your conditions seems to work fine, but i need to check for "_" and "-",, means to say i need only A-Z, 0-9...

Comment: @Lucky: You should accept answer which works for you. And clarify your question if your intent doesn't seem to be correctly communicated across.

Comment: @nhahtdh This is an excellent point, I modified the answer to include a code sample.

Comment: @nhahtdh: this Regex worked for me, just thought of adding some more to it, in case i have a PNo which contains" _ or - "

Comment: There are more scenarios. For example, your regex returns `false` for "AXD123A".

Comment: @Keppil You're right, I needed to use `find` instead of `matches`. [This is now fixed](http://ideone.com/QkwLE).

Answer (score 7):

## Here is the regex for you

**Basics:**

Match in the current line of string: `.`

Match 0 or any amount of any characters: `*`

Match anything in the current line: `.*`

Match any character in the set (range) of characters: `[start-end]`

Match one of the regex from a group: `(regex1|regex2|regex3)`

Note that the start and end comes from ASCII order and the start must be before end. For example you can do `[0-Z]`, but not `[Z-0]`. Here is the ASCII chart for your reference
[image]

**Check the string against regex**

Simply call `yourString.matches(theRegexAsString)`

**Check if string contains letters:**

Check if there is a letter: `yourString.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*")`

Check if there is a lower cased letter: `yourString.matches(".*[a-z].*")`

Check if there is a upper cased letter: `yourString.matches(".*[A-Z].*")`

**Check if string contains numbers:**

`yourString.matches(".*[0-9].*")`

**Check if string contains both number and letter:**

The simplest way is to match twice with letters and numbers

`yourString.matches(".*[a-zA-Z].*") && yourString.matches(".*[0-9].*")`

If you prefer to match everything all together, the regex will be something like: Match a string which at someplace has a character and then there is a number afterwards in any position, or the other way around. So your regex will be:

`yourString.matches(".*([a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-zA-Z]).*")`

## Extra regex for your reference:

**Check if the string stars with letter**

`yourString.matches("[a-zA-Z].*")`

**Check if the string ends with number**

`yourString.matches(".*[0-9]")`

Answer (score 5):

This should solve your problem:

```
^([A-Z]+[0-9][A-Z0-9]*)|([0-9]+[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)$
```

But it's unreadable. I would suggest to first check input with "^[A-Z0-9]+$", then check with "[A-Z]" to ensure it contains at least one letter then check with "[0-9]" to ensure it contains at least one digit. This way you can add new restrictions easily and code will remain readable.

Answer (score 1):

What about `([A-Z].*[0-9]+)|([0-9].*[A-Z]+)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using (([A-Z]+[0-9])|([0-9]+[A-Z])) .It should solve.

Answer (score 0):

use this method:

```
  private boolean isValid(String str)
  {
    String Regex_combination_of_letters_and_numbers = "^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
    String Regex_just_letters = "^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+$";
    String Regex_just_numbers = "^(?=.*[0-9])[0-9]+$";
    String Regex_just_specialcharachters = "^(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])[@#$%^&+=]+$";
    String Regex_combination_of_letters_and_specialcharachters = "^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])[a-zA-Z@#$%^&+=]+$";
    String Regex_combination_of_numbers_and_specialcharachters = "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])[0-9@#$%^&+=]+$";
    String Regex_combination_of_letters_and_numbers_and_specialcharachters = "^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])[a-zA-Z0-9@#$%^&+=]+$";

    if(str.matches(Regex_combination_of_letters_and_numbers))
        return true;
    if(str.matches(Regex_just_letters))
        return true;
    if(str.matches(Regex_just_numbers))
        return true;
    if(str.matches(Regex_just_specialcharachters))
        return true;
    if(str.matches(Regex_combination_of_letters_and_specialcharachters))
        return true;
    if(str.matches(Regex_combination_of_numbers_and_specialcharachters))
        return true;
    if(str.matches(Regex_combination_of_letters_and_numbers_and_specialcharachters))
        return true;
    return false;
  }
```

You can delete some conditions according to your taste